# How do I fly in Creative Mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have heard that we can fly in the "new" creative mode (added in Beta 1.8).  How do you do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To fly you double tap <kbd>space</kbd>, and to descend you hold <kbd>shift</kbd>.

Comment: And to descend, press shift. Took me some research to find that.

Comment: But I press double Space bar and he only jumped

Comment: Then you're either not on 1.8 or you're on a Survival map.

Comment: Or you're experiencing some decent lag.

Comment: You can also double tap the space bar again to descend quickly (turns off flying/no-gravity mode).

Comment: Ditto, it didn't work for me but what is 1.8?

Comment: @jody 1.8 is one of the versions of Minecraft: I believe it's the current version as of writing this, with 1.9 coming out soon.

Comment: I *am* in creative mode, I have 1.8.1, I did double tap space (quickly, slowly, whatever), and I just jumped (I *do* have a huge lag).

Comment: I am actually looking for the console command to fly in creative mode. Any clue?

Comment: When you hit shift, it is actually the sneak command. If the player has toggle turned on for sneak, they have to hit shift again before flying is possible.